# WPS descriptions via OWS describeprocess

Tags: geoserver, wps, ows

When following [these instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/operations.html) to obtain descriptions of various WPS descriptions it's specified to go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeProcess&identifier=JTS:buffer
```

On my geoserver instance though, that request yields the following response:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://mygeoserver:80/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
<ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( ows )</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I do have wps installed and have successfully ran some wps requests. Is there something I need to do to enable ows?

**Edit**

I'm on version 2.10.0 and the request was edited to say localhost only to hide the real server name. 
Also, `http://localhost/geoserver/ows?service=wps&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities` does work

Here is a snip of capabilities:

[image]

Actually I just reran `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeProcess&identifier=JTS:buffer` and it's working now. Not really sure what was going on yesterday. I'll keep an eye on it; what's the proper stack etiquette in this case? Do I just close the ticket?

Comment: Does GetCapabilities query work? Is `localhost` really the machine you are running your WPS requests on?

Comment: What version of GeoServer are you running

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output, it would seem there is no WPS plugin installed in your GeoServer.